# How to align imageView to right while constraining the size using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout, what I want to achieve is align the `middle` ImageView to the `left` of `promo` ImageView (so instead of being centered it will be pushed to right), I know I can do this by deleting this constraint rule `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"` the problem is the `middle` ImageView size may vary so if I delete this constraint and the Image size is too big it will overlap with `logo` ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/promo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/promo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For the regular case should look like this:

[image]

And for the case the image is too big should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` will solve your problem (with width set to `0dp`). The middle `ImageView` will have the same size as if using `wrap_content`, but will be limited by constraints (i.e. it won't expand beyond them).

Updated code:-

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/middle"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/middle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/promo"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/promo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: But is still centered and I want the middle to be aligned to the right (the first image)

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution for your case:
I think i will wrap your middle image inside a layout (RelativeLayout in my exp), set `android:layout_width="0dp"` and

`app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/promo"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"`

so that this layout can not overlay your corner image.
Then put your middle image inside it then set the gravity to the right. This will never cause image overlay whatever the size of the middle image is. ^^
Hope that help.

```
<RelativeLayout
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/promo"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/small"
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: big size case] [image: small size case]